# Receiving a checkbox's unchangeable status based on a model

Tags: html, angular

I have A form with several Items, including some check boxes that need to receive their status from the data service/ a model.

```
<div class="col">
  <label for="expired">IsExpired</label>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="expired" disabled>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is in the class of **card.model.ts**

```
expired: boolean;
```

and **data.service.ts:**

```
new CardModel('4',new Duration(2, 0), new LessonModel('#5DC878', 'Bialogy'), 'just the first part', false,true,new Date(2018,11,11,13,30),new Date(2018,11,11),true,false)
```

I have tried to put `[(ngModel)] = "expired"` into the input tag but I receive an error:

> Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of
>   'input'

what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

## Try this:-

## html

```
 <div class ="col">
        <label for="expired">IsExpired</label>
            <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="expired"  [checked]="checkedStatus">
           <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checkedStatus" name="ele_name"/> <=== add name
            </div>
     </div>
```

## ts

```
checkedStatus = true;
```

Comment: but what if the checked status is not true? I want to put it like the server says, that data service is just an example